# Time Machine Backups are now all failing - can't find reason

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I'm on MacBook Pro running 13.2.1 with all recent updates. I have 3 backup volumes. One is APFS. Two are HFS Extended. All external drives, as well as the internal drive have all passed Disk Utility "First Aid" checks with no issues.

A few weeks ago, my backups just stopped completing. They'll get about 50% through and then stop with no obvious explanation.

The only common entries I can find in the logs are these:

```
com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
com.apple.backupd.status.xpc: connection invalid
com.apple.backupd.xpc: connection invalid
Failed to create volume info from disk '<TMDisk: 0x7f93c4043e00> '/System/Volumes/Data/home'', error: missingURLForRemounting
```

These lines just repeat at various intervals.

Here are the things I've tried:

- Ran First Aid on all disks, containers, and volumes
- Removed the backup disk from Time Machine, rebooted, and re-added it
- Booted into safe mode and tried the backup there (did not help)
- Used "Amphetamine" app to ensure that the Mac did not sleep during attempted backup
- Deleted local snapshots
- Deleted in-progress backups

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Comment: This is the key:  `error: missingURLForRemounting`. This is telling you that the mount point it was using previously no longer exists so it can’t backup.  Is your Mac set to sleep?  Are the external drives on a hub and if so, is it powered (or do the drives have their own PS?). That’s good detective working finding those particular log entries.  Now we just have to get you sorted!

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I ran with the "Amphetamine" app to ensure that the Mac did not sleep. The external drives are connected directly. One is USB-powered. The other two have external power. I'm getting the same problem on all three drives.

Comment: Sleep is just one factor.  If your drives draw too much power (simultaneously) from the USB bus, it can cause your drives to eject.  If you have a powered hub, try plugging your two drives into it.  Are you backing up to all three drives or just one?  Is the backup drive the externally powered drive?

Comment: In one location (at my main desk), I have the two drives with external power supplies. Time Machine just alternated between the two. Never had an issue. In my mobile location, I have a LaCie bus-powered drive. None of the locations/configurations are backing up anymore. I don't think I have any evidence that the drive is ejecting. Again, all was fine in both locations. Last successful backup on all 3 was about three weeks ago.

Comment: Ok.  I was under the impression it was 3 drives on a single MBP.  On the machine that is using the two drives, it is safe to assume that you’re alternating drives for backup?  If so, can you take one, format it clean with APFS and create a clean backup on it?

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem. missingURLForRemounting is not pointing to the backup drive in my case. In fact, the URL is the same - /System/Volumes/Data/home... Have no idea where to look for a solution. This started to happen ever since I moved to an M2 Pro laptop...

Comment: Any luck? Facing the same problem.

Comment: My guess is that "missingURLForRemounting" only appears when you have Time Machine settings open. If I don't open settings, the error doesn't show up... Regarding slow backup - I ended up replacing backup disk, my old one was failing. Time Machine works perfectly ever since.

Comment: I've been trying to diagnose an excruciating slow Time Machine process for months. (It takes hours and even days to even count the millions of changes before starting the backup.) I get the same `missingURLForRemounting` for `/System/Volumes/Data/home` error every minute like clockwork. But I don't know if's related. As for me, booting into safe mode unblocks everything. Dunno what's going on…

Comment: Had the same problem today, tried a backup to my TrueNAS TimeMachine SMB share and I can't proceed anymore. Last succesful backup on 21/7, I've been away for a while and now I can't backup anymore.

Comment: @mlevin, I believe that `/System/Volumes/Data/home'', error: missingURLForRemounting` in the logs may be a red herring, because I had it in my logs, before, during and after successful backup. I did not however, have your completion failure.

Comment: FYI, `Failed to create volume info from disk '<TMDisk: 0x7fce1c182600> '/System/Volumes/Data/home'', error: missingURLForRemounting` shows up even while a backup is _not_ running. I agree it's a red herring. It pops up every 1 min, and only while TM SysPrefs panel is open.